# left bar button items in navigationBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

In iOS5 we have leftBarButtonItems that we can set to a navigation bar, how can I do this for pre-iOS 5? I basically have an array of UIBarButtonItem that I wanted to set the bar to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can build own bar, and add it as left button:

```
    UIBarButtonItem *firstButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"First" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(firstButtonAction:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *secondButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Second" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(secondButtonAction:)];

    UIToolbarTransparent *toolbar = [UIToolbarTransparent new];

    [toolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 140,44)];
    [toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstButton, secondButton, nil]];

    UIBarButtonItem *customBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:toolbar];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarButton;
```

UIToolbarTransparent

.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UIToolbarTransparent : UIToolbar {

}
```

.m

```
#import "UIToolbarTransparent.h"

@implementation UIToolbarTransparent

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.opaque = NO;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.translucent=YES;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: What is a `UIToolbarTransparent`?

Comment: It's my own extension to UIToolbar, which adds transparent background.

Answer (score 2):

samfisher is right, but you can just use a custom UIView that contains your UIButtons, than use that UIView as a (single) leftBasButtonItem